# Can I use "realise" like this?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Examples of "realise a goal/plan/something", it means "*to make it happen*" or "*to achieve things you hope for or plan for*"

> **Cambridge**: They finally **realized their goal** of buying a summer home.
>
> **The Independent**: I intended to deliver them as soon as I returned to the UK, but more than two years passed before I had the time and funds necessary to **realise my plan**.

**I think the following usage is wrong because "realise my plan / goal" means to make it happen. But, in the following context, it means "finishing a project plan", and I guess this is wrong.  I need to comprehend this because I prepare for an English test, and they like these things for some reason. What do you think?**

*I wasn't able to write to you earlier because I had a lot of work. I had to **realise a plan of a project** and I was on a tight schedule.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wasn't able to write to you earlier because I had a lot of work. I
>   **had to realise a plan of a project** and I was on a tight schedule.

According to [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/realize), realize means to achieve or accomplish. In the above sentence "realize" does not make sense, because your goal, from the perspective of time, was not to *realize (accomplish),* but to *finish* a project.

Also, *reali**z**e* is preffered spelling in American English and *reali**s**e* in British English ([Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/realise-realize/)).

So, you could write:

> I wasn't able to write to you earlier because I had a lot of work. I
>   **had to finish a project** and I was on a tight schedule.